# Razer Phone 2 showing wrong size for the SD card and performance of the card is not ok

Tags: sd-card

I have the following setup:

- Razer Phone 2 (Android Phone)
- Samsung EVO 128 GB SD card SDXC class 10 (Yellow one)
- SD Card formatted as internal storage from the Razer phone

After using the phone for couple of months the performance of the phone started to get effected. The I checked and found that the SD card was sowing 256 GB but the card is actually 128 GB.

[image]

I have double checked the card physically and it is a 128 GB card.

Now how do I reformat the SD card so that it is corrected (found a video on how to do that) and then copy my data back to the card so that it works as before. The card is encrypted so the copied data will not make sense. But as long as it works after I copy back that will do.

I do not have another card where I can clone this card. I plan to copy to my windows machine, format and then copy-back the content of the card.

Any suggestion on the steps/measures I have to take to have the card corrected and retain the data?

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to decrypt the data first, then copy it off for re-formatting. I'm not sure if Samsung's Tizen OS supports formatting the external SD card in recovery or not, otherwise, it can be reformatted via `fastboot`, though I'm unsure if Samsung's Tizen OS allows formatting the external SD via `fastboot` on a bootloader locked device. There are Android apps that can format, however you'll want to do research and only install one that's been reviewed by a major 3rd party (Android Authority, CNET, TechSpot, etc.), else it can be formatted on a PC.

Comment: Its not a Samsung phone tho.

Comment: I misread the first and second bullets =] Disregarding the Samsung mention, all the information would still apply _(the only meaningful difference is the RAZER uses Android, whereas Samsung uses a highly customized version called Tizen and implements a different security feature called Knox, neither of which are relevant to your issue)_

Comment: @JW0914 I am sorry but why do you mention Tizen OS here? It is never mentioned in the question. The question is only about Android.